# Returning pmap results as columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, purrr

I want to divide each column in list a by a corresponding column in list b and then return the ratio as a new column in a dataframe that already exists.

I figured out a general way to do it using the following code (using the diamonds package as an example):

```
library(tidyverse)

results <- list(
  lst("depth", "table", "price"),
  lst("x", "y", "z")
) %>%
  pmap_dfc(~diamonds %>% mutate(var = !!sym(.x)/!!sym(.y))) %>%
  select(c(1:ncol(diamonds)), matches("var")) %>%
  rename(new1 = var,
         new2 = var1,
         new3 = var2)
```

My problem is that this duplicates the entire dataframe for each new variable I'm creating, and I then need to deselect these duplicated columns. This isn't an issue here, but might be when I need to do this with 1) more variables and/or 2) larger dataframes.

Any advice on how to *only* create the new columns and bind them to the diamonds dataframe (i.e. avoid having to use the `select` function in my code)?

**EDIT**

The desired result is what's currently in the `results` object above (& pasted below) -- the process of getting there in my code just feels wrong to me.

```
> results
# A tibble: 53,940 x 13
   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z  new1  new2  new3
   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 0.23  Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43  15.6  13.8  134.
 2 0.21  Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31  15.4  15.9  141.
 3 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31  14.0  16.0  142.
 4 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63  14.9  13.7  127.
 5 0.31  Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75  14.6  13.3  122.
 6 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48  15.9  14.4  135.
 7 0.24  Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47  15.8  14.3  136.
 8 0.26  Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53  15.2  13.4  133.
 9 0.22  Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49  16.8  16.1  135.
10 0.23  Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39  14.8  15.1  141.
# ... with 53,930 more rows
```

Comment: @MrFlick edited post above to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `transmute()` and then bind new cols to original df:

```r
library(tidyverse)

results <- list(
  lst("depth", "table", "price"),
  lst("x", "y", "z")
) %>%
  pmap_dfc(~diamonds %>% transmute(var = !!sym(.x)/!!sym(.y))) %>%
  bind_cols(diamonds, .)
```

Comment: Thanks! I always forget about `transmute`, and it seems like exactly what I want for this!

Answer (score 2):

You can generate those three new columns separately. Since the order is the same, you can then use `bind_cols` to concatenate it.

I just wanted to avoid using intermediate variables so I wrote everything in a pipeline.

```r
diamonds %>%
    bind_cols(
        list(
            lst("depth", "table", "price"),
            lst("x", "y", "z")
        ) %>%
            pmap_dfc(~diamonds[[.x]]/diamonds[[.y]]) %>%
            {
                colnames(.) <- c("var1","var2","var3")
                return(.)
            }
    )
```

```r
# A tibble: 53,940 x 13
   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z  var1  var2  var3
   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 0.23  Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43  15.6  13.8  134.
 2 0.21  Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31  15.4  15.9  141.
 3 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31  14.0  16.0  142.
 4 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63  14.9  13.7  127.
 5 0.31  Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75  14.6  13.3  122.
 6 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48  15.9  14.4  135.
 7 0.24  Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47  15.8  14.3  136.
 8 0.26  Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53  15.2  13.4  133.
 9 0.22  Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49  16.8  16.1  135.
10 0.23  Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39  14.8  15.1  141.
# ... with 53,930 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to compose unevaluated expressions that capture the desired computation, then pass those expressions directly to mutate:

```
# Inputs
a <- c("depth", "table", "price")
b <- c("x", "y", "z")

# Compose unevaluated expressions
e <- map2( a, b, ~expr(!!sym(.x)/!!sym(.y)) )

# Pass them to mutate using unquote-splice
R <- diamonds %>% mutate( !!!set_names(e, c("new1","new2","new3")) )

# Compare to desired output
all_equal( R, results )     # TRUE
```